# calculate/get hidden div width in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular, I have a hidden `div` which should be visible on an event.
Event triggers corresponding method. so far so good.
But i need to calculate position of the `div` just before showing it. I use following code in order to get boundary of `div` and calculate actual position, **But the width of `div` is zero, because it is hidden.**

```
EventTriggerMethod(myDiv){
  console.log(myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  //OR
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(myDiv).width);
  //Both return 0 when div is hidden.
}
```

How can i get actual width of a div while it is invisible?

Comment: I don't think that you can get something else than zero in that case. The hidden attribute sets `display: none` on the div. When the div becomes visible, its size depends on the new `display` style attribute (`block`, `inline-block`, `inline`, etc.), which is not know while the div is hidden.

Comment: How do you hide the div? with *ngIf?

Comment: I use `<div ... [class.show]="ShowDropdownContent">` which has `.show{display:block;}`

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm wondering, how dropdowns and menus calculate boundary of container before showing their `popup-context`? So they can show all of the hidden popup-context properly.

Answer (score 1):

An element must be visible and not have `display:none` to be able to calculate its size. The two ways I have seen to get around this are:

1) Place the component way off screen and calculate the size.
2) Turn off `display:none`, calculate the size and then turn `display:none` back on.

As long as you do #2 in the same function it will never show since the re-draw functionality of the browser will not happen until after you function finishes. And since `display:none` is turned back on by the end of your function the element will never show.